# The position of the object when in contact with the ground

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a cube and
I have a floor. I want an event to happen when the object falls to the ground in a specific position like the one in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIjsK.jpg)

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html

Comment: Thanks, but I want a way to write a code that executes when the cube falls in a specific position like this position

Comment: So, do you need an explanation or just code?

Comment: I need to explain simply I just want when I throw the cube up and when it goes down in this position something happens and sorry for taking so long

Comment: You should check the OnColisionEnter event. But expecting the physic engine to have a cube at a specific position seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Get the rotation of the cube in the desired position and save it in a Quaternion.
Add colliders to Ground and Cube. One of the colliders should have a Rigidbody. In the OnCollisionEnter function check if the collision is between the ground and the cube and if its true then check if the rotation of the cube is equal to the desired position(with some tolerance). Then add your required code.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
private override void OnCollisionEnter()
{
    if (this.position == collisionPosition && this.rotation == collisionRotation)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Unity but I want to make the cube fall on only one axis at a time Can I put an empty object in each axis of the cube but there will be a problem when it falls on all three axes together